# How can you connect to a database inside a k8 cluster that's behind a headless service?

Tags: kubernetes

given a database that is part of a statefulset and behind a headless service, how can I use a local client (outside of the cluster) to access the database? Is it possible to create a separate service that targets a specific pod by its stable id?

Comment: My guess, you have to specify a selector in your headless service. Having the selector the P8S creates Endpoints records in the API, (IP addresses) that point directly to the Pods backing the Service. Look at this https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: Hey Denis, thanks for the answer, would I be able to access the pod externally (outside the cluster) with your suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can conect to this database service

You can use

Port-forward : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/

Service as LoadBalancer : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer

Service as Nodeport : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport

Example MySQL database running on K8s : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.6
        name: mysql
        env:
          # Use secret in real usage
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

The easiest way is to try with `port-forwarding` :

```
kubectl port-forward -n <NAMESPACE Name> <POD name> 3306:3306
```

using the above command you can create the proxy from local to K8s cluster and test the `localhost:3306`

This is not a method for **Prod** use case it's can be used for **debugging**.

NodePort : Expose the port but use the worker node IPs so if worker not get killed during autoscaling IP may changed with time

I would recommend creating a new service with the respective **label** and type as `LoadBalancer`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! port-forwarding looks promising for my needs. I was able to get it working with the `LoadBalancer` approach, but I'm concerned it's not the best approach because it can't target a specific pod, is that correct? Say I had a master and slave db and I only wanted to connect to the master pod, would I be able to do that with a `Loadbalancer`?

Comment: You are right absolutely as Loadbalancer forwarding the Traffic from the service level there is no change each time we will get connected to the same pod. Service forward the traffic to PODs in Round robbin manner so.

Comment: Now what i have experienced till now with database headless services, especially with redis headless service, we hit the service it will return the IP values of both master and slave and based on that application connect to master of slave. Doc : https://redis.io/topics/sentinel

Comment: i am not sure about the database you are using but each have different replication method and connection setup however sharing redis example here : https://medium.com/@amila922/redis-sentinel-high-availability-everything-you-need-to-know-from-dev-to-prod-complete-guide-deb198e70ea6